# Excel VBA Data Export

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I have written to export data from access to excel but can not see any records.

```
Sub copyFromRecordset()

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set wipData = New ADODB.Recordset

    conn.ConnectionString = conStr
    conn.Open

    With wipData
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .Source = "WipBin"
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

    Worksheets.Add
    Range("A2").copyFromRecordset wipData

    wipData.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

please advice

Comment: please suggest some code changes which does not contain ADODB. Fields

Comment: "can not see any records" - what *can* you see?  Does anything happen when you run this?

Comment: First, what is your `conStr`. Second, what is your `[Source]` or *command text*. You supplied `"WipBin"`, is that a table?

Comment: with the above code I could manage to display all the records in excel sheet .but i am unable to get fields(headers) in excel sheet.

Comment: ADODB.fields giving invalid use of property. Connection String :"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\SagarDixit\Documents\FilmDatabas.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;" and yes "WipBin" is source table name

Comment: CopyfromRecordset doesn't copy the field names, only the records.  You need to loop over the recordset's Fields collection and write each one's Name to the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not Simply use the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` method

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "TABLE name", "filelocation"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/acspreadsheettype-enumeration-access